# How to change ARGB Android image format into RGB image format to be used in opencv?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk, image-formats

I have a bitmap in ARGB format in android

```
 Bitmap bitmapRGB=Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImageMat.cols(),capturedImageMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

I send this image into Android NDK part to process the image using Opencv libaray in C++. Now i want to change the ARGB format into RGB format and then change it to BGR because Opencv uses BGR format. At first i want to change using cvtColor method in opencv but there is no ARGB2RGB conversion. I also tried to see how opencv team change BGRA2BGR in [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cvtColor&type=) and based on that to write a code to change ARGB2RGB but am unable to find the function in opencv source code.

Comment: Use `Utils.bitmapToMat()` to convert the bitmap to an OpenCV `Mat` type. It will store them in the Android ordering of RGB. You can then convert it to BGR if you want with `cvtColor()`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds no Utils.bitmapToMat() mehod does not change ARGB to RGB I checked the number of channels after Utils.bitmapToMat() using  like 
    int capturedImageMatChannel=capturedImageMat.channels();  it returns 4.

Comment: What if you just swap around the channels? See the example at the bottom of the function [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels).

Comment: Ok i will see examples like that @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: why there is down vote for this question? at least tell me what is wrong with my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087436/alexander-reynolds) i swapped the image channels using [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mixchannels#void%20mixChannels(const%20Mat*%20src,%20size_t%20nsrcs,%20Mat*%20dst,%20size_t%20ndsts,%20const%20int*%20fromTo,%20size_t%20npairs)) method in opencv. When we use bitmapToMat method the ARGB image format of android is changed into RGBA image format in opencv mat. The code i used to separate the RGBA image format into two different images i.e RGB and A

```
cv::Mat inputImage = *(cv::Mat *) inputImageAddress_;
cv::Mat inputImageBGR(inputImage.rows, inputImage.cols,CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat inputImageALPHA(inputImage.rows, inputImage.cols,CV_8UC1);
 int from_to[]={0,2, 1,1, 2,0, 3,3};
Mat out[]={inputImageBGR,inputImageALPHA};
cv::mixChannels(&inputImage,1,out,2,from_to,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Yirga pointed out, OpenCV's `Utils.bitmapToMat()` converts the `ARGB8888` Bitmap to `RGBA` Mat by default.

So a complete Java solution to convert `ARGB8888` Android Bitmap to `RGB` OpenCV Mat would be:

```
Bitmap imageFromAndroid = ... ; // Whatever you have
Mat cvMatRGB = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(imageFromAndroid, cvMatRGB);
Imgproc.cvtColor(cvMatRGB, cvMatRGB, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
```

Imports:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
```